# how can i get complete url of facebook from where the user is directed to my site using php?

Tags: php, facebook, url, header

Actually we have a blog site that publish news. we share the news link into 2 different pages of fb.. we want to keep record that how many people are coming from each page, i mean which page is giving us more traffic?

we need a code in php please..

Comment: Hi welcome on SO, before post read this please [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer is :**

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

**Warning :**
    Anybody can spoof it at anytime regardless of whether they clicked on a link.

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your reply. i know it but it doesn't work on facebook.. it just give facebook.com but dont give the complete url from where the request coming into my site..

Comment: If Facebook explicitly instructs browsers to not send a referrer, then there is little you can do about that.

Comment: so is there any solution @misorude ?? v need it

Comment: If you check the HTML code Facebook uses for external links, you’ll find `rel="noreferrer"` in there, so no, there is no way to make this work in modern browsers. Maybe Facebook Referral Insights can help you, but you will have to embed the Facebook Pixel to begin with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/referral-insights/